# Removing posted by admin date from a contact form

Tags: panels, emails

I am making a contact form in Drupal with using panels but in contact form it is showing posted by admin date. I want to remove these two things as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: What widgets are you using in panels?  Did you create a node just for the heading or are you using custom panel content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do it

1. For all content of same content type

   - Go to the content type for which you want to hide Author info.
   - Scroll down to see the tabs at the bottom and select Display settings.
   - Uncheck Display author and date information.
   - Save content type
2. For Single Node

   - Go to node.tpl.php and search for $submitted
   - Give below condition for you case

     ```
     if ( arg(0) == 'node' AND is_numeric(arg(1)) AND arg(2) == FALSE AND arg(1)==7) {  print $submitted; }
     ```